# Built in speaker work fine but earphone speaker not detected

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.11.0-44-generic.
When I unplug my earphone, both mic and speaker work fine.

When I plug in my earphone, the microphone from that earphone detected and work well. However, the speaker of that earphone not detected. So, my laptop still use the built in speaker.

Previously, both mic and speaker of the earphone work well. I can easy switch them. But, I don't know why the speaker suddenly failed.

[image: sound configuration]

I was following this instruction: https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/, but my earphone speaker not detected, my earphone mic is detected and work fine.

> Update January 10th:
> I tried to boot to ubuntu live usb and checking the earphone, and both speaker and microphone work well.
> Then I comeback to my ubuntu desktop installed in my laptop. And I don't know why my suddenly everything well again.

Now, both earphone mic and speaker work. However, the current problem is there is no output when I try sound test the speaker from Setting menu. Even the speaker work when I tried to listen a video from browser.

Anyone can help me or guide me to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: There's a drop down where it says "Speakers - Built-in-Audio". Can you change that to headphones?

Comment: @KGIII there is no headphone.